# Modeling continuous positive data with variance structure similar to Tweedie with 1.2 variance power, but without excess zeros

Tags: generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution, multiple-imputation, tweedie-distribution

I'm working on a project where I need to model continuous positive data. I found that a Tweedie distribution with a variance power around 1.2 and a dispersion parameter just above 1 fits my data quite well, except for the high probabilities of exact zeros. There are no zeros in the training data since actual zeros would be missing (i.e., such values are not missing at random). However, there could be actual zeros among the missing values, but I estimate that they should be at most around half a percent.

Is there any other model or approach that allows me to fit a distribution that has a variance structure similar to Tweedie with a variance power of 1.2 (i.e., variance increases not much more than linearly with the mean) but doesn't produce excess zeros? Profile likelihood suggests a variance power of 1.6, which would be more reasonable regarding the number of zeros, but when looking at the data (after grouping by estimated expected values) it seems that the variance increases less rapidly than that, closer to a variance power of 1.2.

I'd also be fine with not allowing any zeros at all. However, Gamma and inverse Gaussian distributions have even higher variance powers than the Tweedie with a variance power of 1.6, which already looked too high. Any advice or suggestions on alternative models, transformations, or approaches that could help with this problem would be really helpful!

Background information:

1. One goal of my analysis is to estimate confidence intervals of aggregate totals using multiple imputation.
2. I'm currently using Tweedie GLM with cubic splines as predictors.
3. In my data, there is higher variance in the group with the smallest expected values than for the following group, but after this, the variance appears to increase with the expected values.